# Process VNC Server with image processing script

Tags: vnc, imagemagick

Disclaimer: I don't know a ton about VNC clients and servers so hopefully I am using the right terminology:)

I have a [VNC "server"](https://github.com/FD-/RPiPlay) running on a raspberry pi that accepts my iPhone as a client. When a certain message appears on the screen, for example maybe a low power warning, I want to run a certain script.

My current way of doing this is less than ideal:

- I screenshot and crop every second of the video feed
- I then run an OCR command line script to determine whether the low power message is in fact present, which takes 2-3 seconds.
- When it is recognized, it has already been 5 seconds since the screen has appeared, which isn't ideal and I am trying to lower this number.

Since the VNC server is running, is there some way to access the frames of the VNC server as they come in and process them with a python or shell script? If not, maybe with some VNC recording or VNC client would it be possible?

This section is for the full explanation of my problem.

Since all vnc clients for iOS devices have been depreciated since the iOS 11 jailbroken client, I want to create a custom solution that will still allow me to script where I tap the screen. This solution will consist of 3 parts:

1. Capturing the screen - I determined that airplaying the screen to my PI was a good solution, but am open to others.
2. Scripting to figure out where to click. In my case, I would like to automate clicks for a game (I know, I know) by looking at the screen and determining where I need to click
3. Registering click events - I am using a fake mouse called a teensy (an arduino) to click where I want on the screen

My main problem is step (2): I need a fast and reliable way of processing the screen and outputting where to click. I am currently screenshotting the raspberry pi VNC client, but this is slow and not ideal. So, my overarching question is really **How to capture a VNC server buffer frames within a program**

Comment: Welcome to unix.stackexchange! To help you out we need a little more background on what you want to accomplish (which data do you want to transmit? do you have any restrictions in terms of the network between your Raspi and your phone?). As you have discovered OCR on a VNC connection is far from ideal. Would publishing the data over another type of network connection like HTTP be an option?

Comment: @PLZHELP you can process the logs which is much faster than image processing.

Comment: @Martin sorry for the late reply. I am actually casting from my iPhone using airplay to the raspberry pi VNC server, and apple doesn’t allow screencasting like this outside of third party paid solutions. Can you elaborate on your first concern?

Comment: @binarysta I am looking for something on the screen, how would that help?

Comment: @PeterS I believe we need more information about what you actually want to accomplish to help you out. This feels a bit like an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Comment: Sure. I'll edit the question.

Comment: Edited, please comment if you have more questions.

Comment: Read the link in Martin's comment above. This dialog is triggered by something. Why do you want to apply such an elaborate, convoluted and potentially unreliable mechanism to resolve that something rather than intercepting the trigger directly?

Comment: i have inspected the network traffic, the whole app is client side so I wasn’t sure how to “hook” into the trigger.

Comment: I felt this was the best way since I couldn’t find the trigger, was to monitor the effects of it.

Comment: The network traffic is not triggering the dialog. You seem to be trying to fix the wrong problem. You are still looking in the wrong place.